# CORS error when making request from Swagger UI to Keycloak

Tags: cors, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, keycloak

I'm trying to secure my ASP.NET Core 8 Web API with Keycloak.

I've created a realm and an user with confidential access-type, so it needs a secret. Everything is well implemented I think, but when I try to make a request from Swagger UI, it gives me the following CORS error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:7777/realms/dc2-local/protocol/openid-connect/auth?xxx (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.

When I press the link it redirects correctly to the login page of keycloak and after that, I can make requests correctly without the CORS error, but the first request, when I need to authenticate myself, I get the error

This is my CORS policy:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
    {
        builder
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader();
    });
});

/*other code*/

app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

And this are my request headers:

```
GET /realms/dc2-local/protocol/openid-connect/auth?xxx HTTP/1.1

Host: localhost:7777
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: pt-PT
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Origin: http://localhost:5055
Referer: http://localhost:5055/
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
```

In my Keycloak configuration, I have the following:

- Web Origins: *
- Valid redirect URIs: http://localhost:5055/*